# Angular File Upload Resize & Crop

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, image, ng-file-upload

I have a following problem: the user uploads a logo, which then can be viewed on  page. The thing is, the place for a logo has fixed width and height, and I want to change aspect of the picture uploaded to that size (and resize, but that's not quite important) "the best way possible". That is, I want to crop out a "best fitting" piece of the picture, e.g. if picture's height is low, I want to use full height and crop centerpiece with corresponding width, and if width is little, take the center with full width and corresponding height.

I am currently using ng-file-upload like this:

```
<div class="new-address-company-logo v-middle"
     ng-if="!dc.logo"
     ngf-select
     ng-model="dc.logo"
     name="logo"
     ngf-pattern="'image/*'"
     ngf-accept="'image/*'"
     ngf-max-size="20MB"
     ngf-min-height="200"
     ngf-resize="{width: 320; height: 200}">
    <div layout="column">
        <span>ADD COMPANY LOGO</span>
        <span><i class="material-icons">add</i></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

But `ngf-resize` doesn't work at all, not even stretching the picture (which would certainly be bad, but not even that)

Any help is appreciated

Comment: `ngf-resize="{width: 320, height: 200}"` you have a semicolon there which is not a valid json object. Also use centerCrop: true to crop it to best fit.